# Convert Javascript date format

Tags: javascript

I have a textbox with a date in the format of: 2016.March.23

On the same page I need to pull this date into a javascript Date variable but when I try something like `var date = new Date("2016.March.23");` I get invalid date format.

How can I convert this date format to a JS date variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Date constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) takes one of these formats only.

```
var today = new Date();
var birthday = new Date('December 17, 1995 03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date('1995-12-17T03:24:00');
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17);
var birthday = new Date(1995, 11, 17, 3, 24, 0);
```

You need parse this date using this method.

```
console.log( parseDate("2016.March.23" ) );
function parseDate(str)
{
  var monthArr = ["January","Febuary","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"];
  var dateItems = str.split(".");
  return new Date( dateItems[0], monthArr.indexOf(dateItems[1]), dateItems[2]  );
}
```

Comment: I get this error `0x800a01b6 - JavaScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'split'`

Comment: @sd_dracula what argument did you passed to this parseDate method?

Comment: A Date hence the error. stirng works just fine. Also, how can I add a few days to the date and then convert it back to the original format?

Comment: For converting back to original format you need to get specific values (like year month date) and concatenate them. You can add days by doing `date.setDate( date.getDate()  + 5)`

Comment: That is what I was thinking, but how to get the getMonth() into the format of "March" as it oply returns a number.

Answer (score -1):

Try using your text date in standard ISO format:

new Date('2016-03-23');

That should work.

Comment: Ok, then convert it to the one you can use.